# Trouble using response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, response.redirect

Hi and sorry for my poor english.

I have an Asp.net + Vb.Net application and here is an example of code illustrating my problem :

First I have Default.aspx page with 2 buttons, "Valid" and "Redirect"

```
 Protected Sub butvalid_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butvalid.Click

    If (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("log.txt"))) Then
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("log.txt"))

        Dim tmp As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(lines(lines.Length - 1))
        tmp = tmp + 1

        File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("log.txt"), Environment.NewLine & tmp.ToString)
    Else
        File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("log.txt"), "1")
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub Redirect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Redirect.Click
    Response.Redirect("accueil.aspx")
End Sub
```

Valid button write into a txt file and Redirect is redirecting ...

Here is the page_load code of accueil.aspx :

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
```

The problem is when I click on Redirect button in Default.aspx page, the valid button remains accessible and user can click on Valid button.

How can I disable Valid button after Redirect click ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need a simple javascript for this to disable the other button after the redirect-button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in Page_OnLoad handler and fire at each postback to make sure it is bound. This will disable the button on the client side, and when the page load fires again after the click is and response to the server is done, the button will be enabled again.

```
Redirect.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:"
      + butvalid.ClientID + ".disabled=true;"
      + Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Redirect, null));
```

Comment: This work for me thanks, but I don't understand why between 2 postback the component on page are not available but they are if we do a redirect ...

Comment: I am not clear on what you are saying, can you explain further?

Comment: @Christophe A redirect is not the same as a postback. Its a new page, not the page from when the user clicked the button